# SQL presto filtering for a list of dates?

Tags: sql, data-science, presto

I have a query as below,

```
SELECT column
FROM table
WHERE day IN date ('2019-06-27','2019-07-08', '2019-07-10')
```

the values in the column day are formatted as ***2019-07-07 12:30:15.744***

Currently doesn't let me filter for dates using the date syntax prior to that list of specific dates.

How can I properly code this query to retrieve data for only that list of dates? Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

`date` is a keyword that introduces a date literal, not a list of dates.  Just use it for each value:

```
SELECT column
FROM table
WHERE day IN (date '2019-06-27', date '2019-07-08', date '2019-07-10')
```